# Using Jenkins CLI to configure plugins

Tags: jenkins, puppet

I am working on installing and configuring Jenkins automatically using the Jenkins CLI. I am able to install plugins such as the `Active Directory` plugin, but haven't figured out how to configure it. 
Is it possible to perform such tasks from the CLI? 
 From a Jenkins GUI standpoint, I'd like to check the `Enable security checkbox` under `Security Realm` check the `Active Directory` option, provide parameters to `Active Directory`, and under `Authorization` check the `Anyone can do anything` option.

I'm using a Puppet module (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/rtyler/jenkins) for the automation.

Greetings,
Kenneth

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify their configuration files manually using scripts called from the CLI, then yes.

Else, I don't believe there is. At least, not a general way for all plugins. Plugins are capable of adding CLI commands, as per this documentation page:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

> **Extending CLI**
>
> Plugins installed on Jenkins server can add custom CLI commands. See Writing CLI commands for more details.

So, some of the plugins you're using may have specific commands to configure them from the CLI.

So as far as I know those are your options. Manual configuration through editing their config files, or hoping your plugin includes some commands in the CLI that is specific to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a new Plugin in development called "Configuration as Code Plugin" to provide a way for configuration of plugins using YAML: https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/

They are currently in an early development stage but this could help solve this kind of problem.